# discord message get date time

Tags: java, discord, discord-jda

How can I get discord's message send time, because when I use `msg.getTimeCreated())`, it gets the time but with 4 hours early, what I need to use to be the same as the message time sended?

Here is my code :

```
else {
            String words = objMsg.getContentRaw().substring(5);

            Message msg = event.getMessage();
            Member target = msg.getMember();

            assert target != null;
            objMsgCh.sendMessage("__***WARN :***__\n**DATE:** " + msg.getTimeCreated()).queue();
            objMsgCh.sendMessage("**Message:** " + words + "\n**Warned from:** " + target.getUser().getAsTag()).queue();
        }
```

Comment: Maybe it's just a different time zone than the one your are expecting.

Comment: how I get my timezone?

Comment: Type "timezone [your country]" in a search engine. And please replace [your country] with the country you are living in.

Comment: I get it "Eastern European Summer Time", so how I use this zone ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok use this in ur code
`var embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed() .setTimestamp()`